# Card drawing problem

Tags: probability

We are playing a card game using 54 cards (2 jokers). The cards are shuffled and then attached to a board face down, then numbered 1 thru 54. Everyone pays \$1 for each entry. The object is to find the 3 of hearts. Whomever correctly picks it gets the pot. This is a weekly event. The first week there are 2000 entries (\$2000). One ticket is picked. It is Joe Jones who picked number 6. When card number 6 is removed and turned over, it is the king of spades. No winner. the entry tickets are thrown away

Next week there are 53 cards and 2599 entries. Again a ticket is drawn - this time number 24 by tommy tee. Card number 24 is turned over and it is the 4 of diamonds. This process continues.

Week 3. My question. Which is the best way to win A) play \$52 on one "good" remaining number or B) Play \$52 on each of the remaining numbers? Thank you. Timo

Comment: Both have the same expected value. But keep your money and don't play, it's the best.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see there is any difference.  If $n$ tickets are sold then the chance one of your 52 tickets is drawn is $\frac{52}{n}$ and (given that it is drawn) the chance it has the number corresponding to the 3 of hearts is $\frac{1}{52}$.

So each strategy gives you a $\frac{1}{n}$ chance of winning the pot.

You have not said what happens to the earlier pots.  If they go into the organiser's pocket, you are making a very bad bet: you have spent $\$52$ to get a $\frac{1}{n}$ chance of winning $n$, i.e. an expected gross return of $+\$1$ and an expected net return of $-\$51$.

If pots are rolled over then you have spent  $\$52$ to get a $\frac{1}{n}$ chance of winning $n+4599$, which has a positive return if $n \lt \frac{4599}{51}$, so $90$ or less.  This seems unlikely looking at the previous weeks and the fact that you have contributed $\$52$ towards $n$.

Comment: The money is rolled over each week

Answer (score 0):

What are you paid for a winning bet? The first week there were $2000$ tickets sold but only one person picked a given number? Generally spreading your bets will have the same expectation, but smaller variance.

Comment: In this question at most one of your bets will be considered in detail (and more likely none of them will be).  So spreading your bets makes no difference, so long as you avoid impossible events.